# Flutter health endpoint for kubernetes cluster monitoring

Tags: flutter, kubernetes, health-check

I would like to bring my flutter web application into a kubernetes cluster. To monitor the health of the application I am trying to implement health checks and a health endpoint.

I have tried to implement an endpoint via shelf (dart package) but this resulted in the following error: Unsupported operation: ServerSocket.bind.

Any ideas on how I could implement a (health) endpoint in a flutter web application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.